# Implementing reconnection with URLSession publisher and Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I'm wondering if there is a way to implement reconnection mechanism with new Apple framework Combine and use of URLSession publisher

- tried to find some examples in WWDC 2019
- tried to play with `waitsForConnectivity` with no luck (it even not calling delegate on custom session)
- tried `URLSession.background` but it crashed during publishing.

I'm also not understanding how do we track progress in this way
Does anyone already tried to do smth like this?

upd: 
It seems like `waitsForConnectivity` [is not working](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_8_release_notes) in Xcode 11 Beta

upd2:
Xcode 11 GM - `waitsForConnectivity` is working but **ONLY** on device. Use default session, set the flag and implement session delegate. Method `task is waiting for connectivity` will be invoked no matter if u r using init task with callback or without.

```
public class DriverService: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    public var decoder = JSONDecoder()
    public private(set) var isOnline = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(true)

    private var subs = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var base: URLComponents
    private  lazy var session: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        config.waitsForConnectivity = true
        return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()

    public init(host: String, port: Int) {

        base = URLComponents()
        base.scheme = "http"
        base.host = host
        base.port = port

        super.init()

//      Simulate online/offline state
//
//        let pub = Timer.publish(every: 3.0, on: .current, in: .default)
//        pub.sink { _ in
//            let rnd = Int.random(in: 0...1)
//            self.isOnline.send(rnd == 1)
//        }.store(in: &subs)
//        pub.connect()
    }

    public func publisher<T>(for driverRequest: Request<T>) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {

        var components = base
        components.path = driverRequest.path

        var request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
        request.httpMethod = driverRequest.method

        return Future<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), Error> { (complete) in
            let task = self.session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if let err = error {
                    complete(.failure(err))
                } else {
                    complete(.success((data!, response!)))
                }
                self.isOnline.send(true)
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        .map({ $0.data })
        .decode(type: T.self, decoder: decoder)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

extension DriverService: URLSessionTaskDelegate {

    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, taskIsWaitingForConnectivity task: URLSessionTask) {
        self.isOnline.send(false)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `retry(_:)` yet? It’s available on `Publisher`s and reruns the request upon failure.

If you don’t want the request to immediately rerun for all failures then you can use `catch(_:)` and decide which failures warrant a rerun.

Here's some code to achieve getting the progress.

```
enum Either<Left, Right> {
    case left(Left)
    case right(Right)

    var left: Left? {
        switch self {
        case let .left(value):
            return value
        case .right:
            return nil
        }
    }

    var right: Right? {
        switch self {
        case let .right(value):
            return value
        case .left:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension URLSession {
    func dataTaskPublisherWithProgress(for url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Either<Progress, (data: Data, response: URLResponse)>, URLError> {
        typealias TaskEither = Either<Progress, (data: Data, response: URLResponse)>
        let completion = PassthroughSubject<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), URLError>()
        let task = dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data, let response = response {
                completion.send((data, response))
                completion.send(completion: .finished)
            } else if let error = error as? URLError {
                completion.send(completion: .failure(error))
            } else {
                fatalError("This should be unreachable, something is clearly wrong.")
            }

        }
        task.resume()
        return task.publisher(for: \.progress.completedUnitCount)
            .compactMap { [weak task] _ in task?.progress }
            .setFailureType(to: URLError.self)
            .map(TaskEither.left)
            .merge(with: completion.map(TaskEither.right))
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that `retry` is used in cases like "I failed to load smth while online". In case of unreachable connection you publisher will try to publish response for `retry(2)` - 3 times and then finishes with error, isn't it?

Btw it's interesting solution with progress, I'll give it a try some day

Comment: Please test the solution and mark the answer as correct if it works, that way other users can know.

Comment: Using `.publisher(for: \.progress.completedUnitCount)` seems to raise "BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBPLATFORM: Trying to recursively lock an os_unfair_lock"

what does work for me is:
`task.publisher(for: \.progress).flatMap { $0.publisher(for: \.fractionCompleted )}`

Answer (score -1):

I read your question title several times. If you mean reconnect the URLSession's publisher. Due to the `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` has two results. Success output or Failure (a.k.a `URLError`). It's not possible to make it reconnect after the output produced.

You can declare one subject. e.g

```swift
let output = CurrentValueSubject<Result<T?, Error>, Never>(.success(nil))
```

And add a trigger when network connection active then request resources and send the new `Result` to the output. Subscribe output in the other place. So that you can get *new* value when network back-online.