# Receive task progress from `URLSession.dataTaskPublisher`

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, combine

It is possible to receive progress updates about a `URLSessionTask` by implementing the `URLSessionDataDelegate.urlSession(_:dataTask:didReceive:)` delegate method, and using the delegate-style "task, task.resume()" style of invocation.

With the Combine flavor of the API, this does not appear to be possible. Using `URLSession.dataTaskPublisher(for:)` returns a publisher that publishes the `(Data, URLResponse)` tuple upon completion, but never invokes the delegate method. In that way, it is very similar to the `URLSession.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` method, which invokes `completionHandler` with the final result, and not in-process `Progress` reports.

Am I missing any API or pattern to allow progress reporting, or does the Combine flavor of URLSession task handling not offer a way to retrieve progress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything. To retrieve the progress information you would need to construct your own Future and not use the built-in data task publisher.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Have you seen any useful patterns for publishing more than one stream from an API? I'm currently looking at returning an object with various `*publisher` properties (e.g., `resultPublisher`, `progressPublisher`), which feels icky. The other thing I'm considering is accepting a `PassthroughSubject<Progress, Never>` on the API for interested folks to be notified, but again...icky.

Comment: Actually I don't see why result publisher and progress publisher are icky.

Comment: Also there's already some good discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61102801/how-do-i-check-the-current-progress-of-urlsession-datataskpublisher and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836518/implementing-reconnection-with-urlsession-publisher-and-combine